# Laravel count relationship of relationship

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to count the amount of rows in a a relationship which is a via a relationship on the main table. I have 3 tables in total..

Surveys:

`| id |`

Questions:

`| id | survey_id |`

Responses:

`| id | question_id |`

I am trying to get the total count in the responses table from the surveys table. I have all of the relationships set up but I cannot seem to get the total count.

I have tried to do `->withCount('questions.responses')` but this results in a 500 error. I know i can loop through but didn't know if there was a more efficient way to do it within Eloquent.

Comment: you have a HasManyThrough relationship defined?

Comment: Didn't even think abotu this, can you add an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using a [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship.

In your model:

```php
/* Survey.php */

public function responses()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Response::class, Question::class);
}
```

Then in your controller:

```php
/* SurveyController.php */

public function index()
{
    // Get your surveys with your desired attribute:
    $surveys = Survey::withCount('responses')->get();

    return view('my_cool_view')->withSurveys($surveys);
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind I updated your question. I was answering while you posted yours, and given that you suggested this approach, I think this is the correct thing to do instead of post one myself. You are free to undo this if you wish. Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, friend. I don't mind at all, Have a good day :)